# word table of contents

Tags: vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

My document uses styles Heading 1 and Heading 2 as well as MyHead1, MyHead2. I want to create a table of contents with only MyHead1 and MyHead2 entries. I can do this from the menu using Options in the Table of Contents and removing the TOC levels from Heading1 and Heading 2 styles.

I want to do this in VBA. I have tried using the recorded macro:

```
With ActiveDocument
    .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=Selection.Range, RightAlignPageNumbers:= _
        True, UseHeadingStyles:=False, IncludePageNumbers:=True, AddedStyles _
        :="MyHead1,1,MyHead2,2", UseHyperlinks:=True, HidePageNumbersInWeb _
        :=True, UseOutlineLevels:=False
    .TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = wdTabLeaderDots
    .TablesOfContents.Format = wdIndexIndent
End With
```

However, the resultant TOC includes the Heading 1 and Heading 2 entries.

I expected the `UseHeadingStyles:=False` to exclude the built-in heading styles but it does not. How do I exclude them?

Answer (score 3):

I would have expected the `UseHeadingStyles:=False` to exclude them too.  If you manually insert the TableofContents and then select the whole table and right click and 'Toggle Field Codes' you will see the field code text for the inserted TOC as:

```
TOC \o "1-9" \h \z \u \t "MyHead1,1,MyHead2,2"
```

The `\o "1-9"` flag here represents the Headings style and if omitted will leave you with the TOC you desire.  Therefore, instead of inserting the TOC using the code you've got this alternative will do the trick.  You will still be able to use `ActiveDocument.TableOfContents(1)` to select it after insertion.

```
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.Text = "TOC \h \z \t " & """" & "MyHead1,1,MyHead2,2" & """"
Selection.Fields.Update
```

For the full list of field code switches for the TOC see here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-HP005186201.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It looks like UseHeadingStyles not working is a bug. I will use the Fields.Add as you suggest.

Comment: That makes sense. If my answer helped you would you mind accepting the answer? :) See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer.

In order to switch off UseHeadingStyles and UseOutlineLevels in the same TableOfContents.Add statement you need UseFields:=True

```
With ActiveDocument
    .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=Selection.Range, RightAlignPageNumbers:= _
        True, UseHeadingStyles:=False, IncludePageNumbers:=True, AddedStyles _
        :="MyHead1,1,MyHead2,2", UseHyperlinks:=True, HidePageNumbersInWeb _
        :=True, UseOutlineLevels:=False _
        UseFields:= True
    .TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = wdTabLeaderDots
    .TablesOfContents.Format = wdIndexIndent
End With
```

Answer (score -2):

On Word toolbar Click  References and Table of contents option
Point the cursor to the beginning of the page where table of contents need to
begin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GoE7.png)