Adding TOC in Word using VBA results in unwanted headings in the TOC
I'm trying to add a TOC in Word using VBA containing the headings:
includedStyles = "Heading 1;1;Heading 2;2;Heading 3;3"

I recorded a macro when manually adding the TOC which gives the desired result, the code shown below.
Dim TOC As TableOfContents
Dim includedStyles As String

' Define which styles to include in the TOC
includedStyles = "Heading 1;1;Heading 2;2;Heading 3;3"

' Delete existing TOC if present
If ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Count > 0 Then
    ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Delete
End If

' Add a new TOC with specified styles
Set TOC = ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add( _
    Range:=Selection.Range, _
    RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
    UseHeadingStyles:=False, _
    IncludePageNumbers:=True, _
    AddedStyles:=includedStyles, _
    UseHyperlinks:=True, _
    HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, _
    UseOutlineLevels:=False _
)

But when I run this code also a style named "Alt Heading 1" and "App H1 Title" is added. I tried multiple variations but can't get the desired result.

When you say these styles are also added, do you mean that they are visible in the field (after toggling field codes) or only that they are visible in the resulting TOC?

Please add the contents of the resulting TOC field to your question to clarify. (Like this: {TOC \o "1-9" \h \z}

Answer was found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17160130/4474833
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.Text = "TOC \h \z \t " & """" & "Heading 1;1;Heading 2;2;Heading 3;3" & """"
Selection.Fields.Update


Correct! The same question includes another answer which also works: add UseFields:=True to your original command.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
